# Rails and foreign keys

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, postgresql, foreign-keys

I've got silly magic problem in rails!

So, I've created table with foreign key (I'm using sparkfly-foreigner gem).

```
class CreateCourses < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :courses do |t|
      t.string :coursename,
      t.integer :subject,
      t.integer :theme,
      t.integer :hours,
      t.decimal :price,
      t.foreign_key :subject, :column => :subject, :dependent => :delete
      t.foreign_key :theme, :column => :theme, :dependent => :delete
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

It works fine in terminal and in my rails webapp.

Then I'm creating another table.

```
class CreateGroupps < ActiveRecord::Migration
  def change
    create_table :groupps do |t|
      t.string :groupname
      t.integer :courseid
      t.integer :number,
      t.foreign_key :course, :column => :courseid, :dependent => :delete
      t.timestamps
    end
  end
end
```

And there magic begins. I'm writing not existing courseid in the web form for Groupps, and it CREATES RECORD IN THE DATABASE!!! When I'm using terminal, i get this

```
rails_dev=> select * from groupps
rails_dev-> ;
 id | groupname | courseid | number |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-----------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 12        |          |      1 | 2011-12-03 02:51:06.154261 | 2011-12-03 02:51:06.154261
(1 row)

rails_dev=> insert into groupps values (2,12,0,0);                                                                                                                                                          ERROR:  insert or update on table "groupps" violates foreign key constraint "groupps_courseid_fkey"
DETAIL:  Key (courseid)=(0) is not present in table "courses".
```

How it could be possible? And when I'm wrong? I'm too newbie in rails and ruby.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This output:

```
 id | groupname | courseid | number |         created_at         |         updated_at         
----+-----------+----------+--------+----------------------------+----------------------------
  1 | 12        |          |      1 | 2011-12-03 02:51:06.154261 | 2011-12-03 02:51:06.154261
(1 row)
```

indicates that you have a NULL in `courseid` and that's just fine as far as your table and foreign key are concerned. You're allowed to have a NULL in a referencing column, you probably want to add `:null => false` to your `courseid`:

```
create_table :groupps do |t|
  t.string :groupname
  t.integer :courseid, :null => false
  t.integer :number,
  t.foreign_key :course, :column => :courseid, :dependent => :delete
  t.timestamps
end
```

BTW, since you're already in [`psql`](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/app-psql.html), you can use `\d groupps` to see your table's structure, constraints (include FKs), and even which FKs refer to your table. You might also be interested in `\pset null`:

> `null`
>   Sets the string to be printed in place of a null value. The default is to print nothing, which can easily be mistaken for an empty string. For example, one might prefer `\pset null '(null)'`.

Comment: Thank you:) I knew that solution must be simple and also there will be my stupid mistake.